# Bind a Dictionary to a CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, dictionary

I've got a `Dictionary<string, bool>` object storing some items and their status: `true` means **enabled**, `false` means **disabled**.

I'd like to bind this object to a `CheckedLIstBox`, or alternatively, bind a `List<string>` and then loop through the `Dictionary` and use the **key** to access the `CheckListBox` items setting their status.

Which is the easiest way?

Comment: May be out of scope but are you tied to WinForms or did you just go that route due to familiarity? WPF makes this trivial.

Comment: @AaronMcIver I'm working on an existing WinForm project and I cannot convert it to WPF...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to avoid the binding altogether. [Microsoft does not promote the use of the DataSource property](http://web.archive.org/web/20100513075027/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/115199/checkedlistbox-datasource-displaymember-valuemember-are-hidden) for a `CheckedListBox`.

> Posted by Microsoft on 5/30/2005 at 10:28 AM
>
> ... We do not support data binding on the `CheckedListBox` control.
> [The `DataSource`, `DisplayMember`, `ValueMember` properties]
> properties are inherited from it base class and cannot be removed so
> we hid them form the property grid and IntelliSense.
>
> The Windows Forms Team.

Use the `AddRange` method to add your collection to the `CheckedListBox` at runtime and be done with it.

Comment: Do you mean `Items.AddRange()`? Can I also bind the boolean values using this method?

Comment: Yes, using the `Items` property you can do a [range of things](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.items.aspx). This would be a one time event, defining the items and then adding them. Overall binding within WinForms is more trouble than it is worth with the exception being the use of a `DataGrid`.